# Calculating the shipping date according to time and holiday in php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to make the code that calculates the expected shipping date when a user submits an order.

So, this will contain a text box to enter a date(datepicker) and submitting it is like placing an order (the aim is to get the order date)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DateTimePicker example</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
             <form id="formsubmit"  method="post" class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <input id="input" class="input" width="312" placeholder="click to select order date" name="datetime" />
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success ml-2">submit</button>
            </form>
    </div>
    
   <!--scripts-->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       
    <script>
         $('#input').datetimepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
            modal: true,
            footer: true
        });
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#formsubmit').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            var datetime = $(".input").val();
            //By Spliting the input control value with space
            var time=datetime.split(' ')[0];
            var date=datetime.split(' ')[1];
            alert(date);
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'functions.php',
                data: {'time': time, 'date': date, 'call': 1},
                success: function(response)
                {
                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
     
                  
               }
                   });
             });
        });
    </script>
    
     
</body>
</html>
```

For the instance, lets just says the seller has decided NOT to ship on certain days of the week. We should be able to change the dates in which they are not shipping.

**function.php**

```
function getShippingDate($orderDate, $oderTime) {
    
    $outOfStock = true;
    //echo date('d-m-Y') , "\n";  // as baseline
    
    $deliveryDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+' . 1+$outOfStock . ' day'));  // treat bool as int: instock=1, outofstock=2
    //echo $deliveryDate , "\n";  // as proof
    
    $allHolidays = array('10-08-2022', '13-08-2022'); //holidays in dates
    while(in_array($deliveryDate,$allHolidays)){
        $deliveryDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$deliveryDate +1 day"));
    }
    return $deliveryDate;

}

if(isset($_POST['call']))
{
  echo getShippingDate($_POST['date'],$_POST['time']);
}
```

Online demo: https://3v4l.org/7YU7e

But the problem is now there is a cut-off time for placing an order that will be shipped on the same day,

```
$cutOffTime = "11";
```

f.e. orders placed before 11 in the morning will be shipped on the same day, else it will only be shipped the next day/next shipping allowed day. Shipping means handing the package to the courier company. Now how can I adjust the time and shipping date?

Comment: I am actually a bit confused, since you are not using the `$orderDate` and `$orderTime` variables inside the getShippingDate() function. Is it correct that the function always calculate the `$deliveryDate` starting from the current date, `date('Y-m-d')`, and not the `$orderDate`?

Comment: Oh sorry My bad...you can use that as date and time parameters. you can add custom starting date insted of current date here https://3v4l.org/7YU7e

Answer (score 1):

You can add an if statement to check if the `$orderTime` is before or after your `$cutOffTime`:

```php
$cutOffTime = "11:00:00";
if($orderTime >= $cutOffTime){ // you can use $ordertime or date("H:i:s") based on your needs
    $deliveryDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$deliveryDate +1 day"));
}
```

full function would be something like this:

```php
function getShippingDate($orderDate, $oderTime) {
    
    $outOfStock = true;
    //echo date('d-m-Y') , "\n";  // as baseline
    
    $deliveryDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+' . 1+$outOfStock . ' day'));  // treat bool as int: instock=1, outofstock=2
    //echo $deliveryDate , "\n";  // as proof

    $cutOffTime = "11:00:00";
    if($orderTime >= $cutOffTime){ // you can use $ordertime or date("H:i:s")  based on your needs
         $deliveryDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$deliveryDate +1 day"));
    }
    
    $allHolidays = array('10-08-2022', '13-08-2022'); //holidays in dates
    while(in_array($deliveryDate,$allHolidays)){
        $deliveryDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$deliveryDate +1 day"));
    }
    return $deliveryDate;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @C.Celora, I simple use push the current date into the holiday to prevent shipping today when ordering is after 11am

```
    $orderTime = "10:00:00"; // order time 
    $deliveryDate = '09-08-2022'; //order date as as today
    $allHolidays = array('10-08-2022','11-08-2022', '12-08-2022','13-08-2022'); //holidays in dates
    $cutOffTime = "11:00:00"; //cutoff time
    
    if($orderTime >= $cutOffTime){ //if user order after 11am
       //order after 11
           array_push($allHolidays, date('d-m-Y')); //adding current date into holiday to prevent shipping today
           while(in_array($deliveryDate,$allHolidays)){ //checking order date in holidays
                   
               $deliveryDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$deliveryDate +1 day")); //check next available day if holiday found
                        
             }
        echo $deliveryDate;
       
    }else{ //if user order before cutoff time
        //order before 11
        
         while(in_array($deliveryDate,$allHolidays)){
             if($deliveryDate == date('d-m-Y')){ //check 
                 $deliveryDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$deliveryDate +1 day"));
             }else{
                 $deliveryDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$deliveryDate +1 day"));
             }
          
         }
        echo $deliveryDate;
        
    }
```